# How to make certain Issues visible only to a specific user group in YouTrack

Tags: youtrack

In our YouTrack project all issues are historically visible to "all users" which is also the group with the same name that shipped with YouTrack.

Now we are adding new users with restricted permissions and they should only see a small part of the issues. They should start seeing no issues at all, and then single issues (old issues and new issues) should selectively made visible to them.

I tried different ways to make this happen, but without success.

1) If I create a group for them "restricted group" - then I can give this group permission to view issues. And then they can see all issues, and if I uncheck the "view issues" privelege checkbox, then they cannot see any issue at all. This does not help me, as they either see all issues or none.

2) I tried to change the "issues is visible to" field in a single issue and set it to "restricted group". But YouTrack won't let me, only "all users" or "project XY Assignees" can be selected here. Edit: this is still true, after I add myself to "restricted group", see `Alex.V`'s [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18340350/362951)

So I deleted the group "restricted group" and tried to work with "assignees":

3) I choose an issue and set its visibility to "My Project Assignees". And then I add a user to the "My Projects Assignees" group. But now the user can see ALL the issues in that project. In the group settings I find out, that the checkbox "Read issues" in the definition of this group's role "Developer" can be unchecked, and this changes visibility. But again for all Issues! And it does not matter If I set the visibility for the issue to "My Project Assignees" or to "All users" - now the user can see no issues at all, after unchecking the checkbox.

This is  YouTrack 4.2.2 (build #6029 [23-May-2013 18:30]

Please show me a way to selectively make issues visible to a group of users and invisible again. I know it is possibly quite simple, so what is my mistake?

---

In the meantime I was able to understand how the view permissions work.

The dropdown box at the top of the issue page acts only as a filter and you can only EXCLUDE users with this dropdown box that could already see the issue when visibility was still set to "all users".

So I think one way to accomplish what I want I will have to change all issues' visibility to let's say "admin1 group" and later switch only some of them back to "all users" so everybody can see those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your second variant, you can only choose a group you belong to in "issue visible to" combobox. Will this variant work for you in other aspects?

Comment: This would be a good solution and I just tried it out. I created a new group "staff" and I added myself and some user to it. But the group still does not appear in the "issue visible to" combobox. I also added a role "observer" to the group, but it is still not available in the combo box.

Comment: And btw. after adding the "observer" role, the other user instantly could see all issues. Which is correct, because our observer role has the "read issue" checked.

Comment: Please not that a user should posses 'Update Issue' permission in order to change the visibility.

Answer (score 3):

OK. I managed to achieve visibility with the help of the post in this: [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18340350/3814392).
In reality it is pretty straight forward when you understand how the permissions work.
There are 2 "components" that take part in achieving this: 
1) The issue visibility (visibility field on an issue which defaults to: All Users)
2) The project's groups/users and their roles.

I'll explain by example:

### Step 1:

Create two groups: **Managers** and **Developers** and assign them to your project: Restricted Project (prefix: RP). Both have roles of developers, so that they can edit an issue's fields, comments description and log work. These 2 groups are the only groups in your project.

### Step 2:

1. Say in your workplace you have 10 users: U1, U2, ..., U10
2. Assign U1 and U2 to Managers *and* Developers
3. Assign U3 and U4 to Developers *only*.

### Step 3:

1. Create a new ticket (RP-1) and change the visibility of this ticket to: Managers
2. Create a new ticket (RP-2) and change the visibility of this ticket to: Developers.

## Result:

1. With this setup, users U5-U10 will not be able to see the RP project or any of it's tickets. Doesn't matter which search they will perform.
2. Users U1 & U2 will be able see/read both tickets: RP-1 and RP-2
3. Users: U3 & U4 will be able to see/read only ticket RP-2

*NOTE:* If you create another ticket: RP-3 with visibility: 'All Users' then any of the users across all groups in the project will be able to see/read this ticket.

I hope this simplify things :)